# Using "quote do" with a "nil" context

Tags: elixir, abstract-syntax-tree

is there an alternative to this non-working code?

```
ast = quote context: nil do 
  x = y 
end
Code.eval_quoted(ast, y: 2)
```

I want the AST to be :  `{:=, [], [{:x, [], nil}, {:y, [], nil}]}` (so the eval knows the `y` is coming from the bindings)

Is it possible or must I create a context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole `quote/1` block has its own context, in the first place. Just passing `y: 2` as the second parameter of `Code.eval_quoted/2` won’t work without bypassing [macro hygiene](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html#macro-hygiene) explicitly.

That said, if one wants to get `y` from the context, they *must* use [`Kernel.var!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#var!/2) within the macro body.

That said, the question cannot be answered as it’s stated: to enforce `y` coming from context, which in turn can be *only* passed to `Code.eval_quoted/2` through explicit bindings, one might use

```elixir
ast = quote do: x = var!(y)
```

but then the question *where `x` comes from then* would be raised.

Comment: Excellent Aleksei, this is what I was looking for. I saw the function in the doc but I did not understand it at the time. Thanks!